# Virtual box not getting connected to internet

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox

am trying to install Hadoop, part of which I have installed Virtual box.

In virtual box -> network settings i have Bridged Adapter 
and in Windows -> Network connections -> Adapter settings -> VirtualBox Host-only Network -> Properties -> Bridged Network Driver is enabled

I have checked the time also in virtual machine, it is fine.

am not able to figure out why internet is not working in my Virtual Box

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Resolved... 
My Corporate network was not allowing any Bridged networks, once i disconnect from corporate network and connect to my home network it worked.

Not sure of low level details though.

Thanks.